# Android by HTML5 / CSS3 / JavaScript

Tags: javascript, android, html, css

Can I create Android applications with HTML5, CSS & JavaScript? Such as (News application, books library, 2D & 3D Games and etc) How can I do?
And what is the platform used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple platform to use would be the cordova platform.
Simple tutorial found here: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/cli/

Install Cordova:
   `npm install -g cordova`

Create project:
    `cordova create CordovaApp`

Upon creating the application you will notice a 'www' folder. Inside you will find the html, css and js files and folders. Modify those according to your requirements

Add Target Device Platform:
    `cordova platform add ios`
or
    `cordova platform add android`

Build the app:
    `cordova build`

Run the app:
    `cordova run android` or `cordova run ios`